# Tableau Replacing Empty Values with 0

Tags: replace, null, tableau-api, zero

In Tableau I am struggling to replace a null/empty value with O. Tableau's ZN(expression) is still just returning a column with all the same empty/null values. Anything else I have tried to do has also been unsuccessful. Has anyone ever experienced this problem and was able to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it a numeric column where you're using ZN? You can also try using IFNULL() instead.